# Designmodo's Startup Design Framework usage with Meteor

Tags: meteor

How can I use Designmodo's Startup Design Framework with Meteor. I've tried a lot of things but couldn't get them to work together.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've tried adding the code to meteor project and removing unnecessary files but I couldn't get flat-ui section.